# Past participle of modal verbs

Tags: grammar, modal-verb, perfect-tense

I have a question about this sentence:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputtgegangen, darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.

Is the verb form *können* right? I think it is supposed to be *gekonnt*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Modalverben* (like *müssen*, *dürfen*, *wollen* und *sollen*, and *brauchen* in specific usages) are an exception to the rule when building perfect tense.

Modal verbs need to form the perfect tense using an *Ersatzinfinitiv* (replacement infinitive) instead of the participle, when there is another  infinitive with the predicate - in your example "mähen".

> Hast du mähen können?

vs.

> Hast du es gekonnt?

(No extra infinitive in the second example's predicate, that is why the perfect is constructed in the "normal" way using the participle)

> Hast du mähen gekonnt?

is not always considered *wrong*, but is accepted in many dialects - and thus in colloquial language - as ok-ish. But maybe shouldn't be used in a scientific article.

Comment: Danke, It is now clear to me :)

Answer (score -1):

Der Satz

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, darum habe ich den Rasen nicht mähen können.

ist richtig.

Man könnte auch sagen:

> Der Rasenmäher ist kaputt gegangen, darum konnte ich den Rasen nicht mähen.

Das Wort "gekonnt" wird generell wenig verwendet und man kann es in diesem Satz nicht verwenden.

Comment: Ich bin nicht bei dir mit deinem letzten Kommentar - Kannst du die Nicht-Verwendung von "gekonnt" irgendwie belegen?