# Ich habe sie essen sehen oder gesehen

Tags: grammar, verb, perfect-tense, past-participle

Wie sagt man richtig auf deutsch?

> Ich habe sie gestern essen **ge**sehen.

oder

> ich habe sie gestern essen sehen.

Comment: Related: [Warum Infinitiv anstatt Partizip-Perfekt? (“Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen gehört” vs “Ich habe dich gar nicht kommen hören”)](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/5187/9551)

Comment: @Loong Which is itself marked as a duplicate already... More duplicates are here http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30616/past-participle-of-modal-verbs and here http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70/why-no-perfect-participle-sie-hat-sich-scheiden-lassen - Some of the answers refer to the *Ersatzinfinitiv* (which is the core of the answer), some don't.